# Unable to install much after server instalation. "unable to find image"?

Tags: server, 22.04, docker

I have Ubuntu Server 22.0.4.3 LTS onto a USB drive.
I installed it onto an oldish computer with one HDD (1tb).
No problems with the installation.
I can sign in and then....

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  $(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME") stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```

Installing the latest:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

Verifying it:

```
sudo docker run hello-world
```

This comes back with this error:

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: 
Error response from daemon: unknown: <html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1> Your browser didn't send a complete request in time. </body></html>. 
See 'docker run --help'
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've done this once before and I'm kicking myself as I'm sure that I've not missed something, have I?

Comment: I have not seen this before because I don't use docker. But the 408 message is likely coming from docker, or dockerhub. There's a bunch of people reporting this message. This doesn't feel like an Ubuntu issue, but a docker one. e.g. https://forums.docker.com/t/http-408-request-time-out-but-not-a-ratelimit-or-dns-issue/113755

Comment: Ah ok, I’ll have a look at docker forums. Thanks for the advice.. appreciated 